# Как прочитать содержимое html страницы?

Tags: golang

Как при помощи средств Golang прочитать `content (содержимое)` исходный код `html` страницы. В документации копался... и ничего не нашел.

Код:

```
package main 

import "fmt"
import "os"
import "net/http"
func main() {
    ress(os.Args[1])
}

func ress(url string) {
    req, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("GetFATAL")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(req.Body)
    }

}
```

Comment: Возможно `defer req.Body.Close()` и `html, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант:

```
req, err := http.Get(url)
// check err
defer req.Body.Close()
b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
// check err
fmt.Printf("%s\n", b)
```

Comment: спасибо, работает)